KEYBOARD Upon initial setup of the latest Ubuntu, my keyboard will not engage to type in Password or Personal info. I am stalled at this stage
KEYBOARD Upon initial setup of the latest Ubuntu 24.04, my keyboard will not engage to type. Personal info in the installation guide the keyboard is the typical aluminum small keyboard that came with the 27"iMac desktop
mid 2011, wireless/bluetooth.

Please avoid vague terms like "latest Ubuntu", and instead say what Ubuntu product (Server? Desktop? Core? etc) and what release you're asking about. Passwords do not show in most products when typed (no stars either as that allows people who can see the screen to see the number of characters typed!), so how can you know password didn't show?  We don't know what product, thus cannot know if dots should appear, but in most they do not.

read [ask] then [edit] your question with further details

You've now provided a release (24.04) so thank you, but not the product details (ie. Server? Desktop?) as their differ including use of different installers.

Thank you for your input. at 72, I was impressed I got as far as installing Flash and Ubuntu in my obsolete iMac 27" Mid 2011. As for the password, it is asking for me to input and it doesn't type anything. That is how I know.

I hooked up a new magic keyboard from mac, problem solved.

I guess you're talking about Ubuntu 24.04 Noble Numbat, is that right? Obviously it's Desktop, not Server, from the question. There is still potentially a query is it Ubuntu or Kubuntu or Edubuntu, etc, but I still don't think this has much bearing on your question (you might be kind to the pedants by answering them though...).
What sort of keyboard is it? Mine is an old one which plugs in to a USB2 slot. I'm guessing that a keyboard with a cable USB or PS/2 might work better than a bluetooth keyboard...
...however, when your computer boots from the installation medium (e.g. USB stick) you can try out how it works before installing. Then you can check the keyboard and get it working somehow hopefully.
Good luck!

Apple's standard aluminum keyboard, just wireless/bluetooth It came with the unit, batteries are charged and it worked before the 24.04 install.

I'm not really a technical person, and I don't have Bluetooth on my old PC, but I'd guess that you might need to turn on Bluetooth. I'm sorry about the negative responses from the experts. Try not to let it bother you.

I found this question and answer. So you do need to go into Bluetooth settings before you do the installation. I hope it will then work for you.

Thanks Visctrix, at 71 I am proud I got this far! As for the biting sarcasm from others, I can give it as well as take it. LOL

I installed a new magic keyboard from Mac. It works, problem solved. Thank you for all your help.
